# Изменение изображения при прокрутке

Tags: html, css

Как можно реализовать вот такую штуку: на сайте http://ginza.ru/msk в самом низу после "еще новости" - при прокрутке страницы изображение тоже прокручивается?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: вы имеет ввиду подвал? когда скролишь страницу картинка стоит на месте?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Можно открыть страницу в developer tools и посмотреть:

```
.row-header-main-footer-picture {
    background-image: url([путь-к-картинке]);
    background-position: 50% 50%;
    background-attachment: fixed;
    background-size: cover;
}
```

как видите фоновая картинка сделана с `background-attachment: fixed;`. Это заставляет картинку "стоять на месте" при прокрутке страницы. А сверху на нее наложены два блока, один с прозрачным фоном (тот, где дата-лого-телефон), второй с белым фоном (заказать доставка-поделитесь отзывом).
Но главное- фон стоит на месте при прокрутке.

Еще раз - воспользуйтесь developer tools любого браузера.